# writing unit test odoo 8

Tags: unit-testing, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to write test cases in odoo 8, but i am unable to run the test cases. I mean nothing happens, no test case runs.
I have created a module and below is my code.

__openerp__.py

```
{
'name': "wms_mobile",

'summary': """
    Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
    subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

'description': """
    Long description of module's purpose
""",

'author': "Your Company",
'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

'category': 'Uncategorized',
'version': '0.2',

# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['web'],

# always loaded
'data': ['views/main_templates.xml'], 
# only loaded in demonstration mode
'demo': [
    'demo.xml',
],
}
```

and i have tests folder with __init__.py and test_location.py
__init__.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from . import test_location
```

test_location.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp.tests.common import TransactionCase

class test_location(TransactionCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(test_location, self).setUp()
        self.LocationObj = self.env['stock.location']

    def test_location(self):
        record = self.LocationObj.search([('name','=','Stock')])
        self.assertEqual(record.id,1)
```

I run the server with --test-enable parameter, But i don't see the test running.

Am I missing Something.

My database has entries also.

Please Help

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to specify the database...(you have to create a test db, so you don't mess up the real db) you want to run the tests on, and optionally the module you want to test, you should also set `log-level` to test to get a more verbose output

```
./odoo.py -c /path/to/configfile.conf -d dbname -u yourmodule --log-level=test --test-enable
```

Comment: Since Odoo 8 it's `odoo.py` ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...`openerp-server` is still there and still works, but on a machine where `#!/usr/bin/env python` points to python3 it wouldn't. and even then you might need to do `python2 odoo.py`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have  to put test_enable = True in your configfile.conf

Comment: Can you expand on this answer?